# The control structure of my function doesn't prevent it from continuing indefinitely. Why?

Tags: c++, algorithm

One problem with using algorithms that "walk" 2 pointers towards each other is that you might have a situation where they miss each other because you move the first forward and the second back without checking for equality in between those operations. I thought the following function I created

```
void zeros_to_back(int * arr, int n)
{
/* 
    arr: Array of integers
      n: Length of arr

    Moves all the zeros of arr to its back.
    Meant to replicate std::partition.
*/
    int * pa (arr);
    int * pb (arr + n);
    while (pa != pb)
    {
       if (*pb != 0)
       {
           if (*pa == 0)
           {
               std::swap(pa, pb);
               --pb;
           }
           else
           {
               ++pa; 
           }            
       }   
       else
       {
           --pb;
       } 
    }
}
```

was sturdy enough to not have that problem, but evidently it isn't, because my program is timing out.

Here's a link where you can test it: http://codepad.org/24DE1GIY

Anyone care to point out what I've done wrong? I can't see it.

Comment: Are you sure you want to swap the pointers and not the value they point to?

Comment: _"Anyone care to point out what I've done wrong? I can't see it."_ Isn't that what a debugger is for? Step through that code and watch how variables change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int * pb (arr + n);
```

you are initializing pb with one element past the end of array. That's not a problem as long as you use it after decrementing.

But

```
std::swap(pa, pb);
```

this will try to swap first element with one past end element which is a problem.

Also you are trying to swap pointers rather than values they are pointing to...

```
std::swap(*pa, *pb);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `std::swap` to swap the POINTERS, not the value they point to. Fix this by using `std::swap(*pa, *pb);`